# How to pass the default value back as input value if you don't want the value to be changed?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I have assigned default values to the input tag. When I try to submit without changing the values of the input tag, the value passed is undefined.

What I want is that if the input value is changed, to update the state value with the new value and if the input tag value is not changed, then to pass the default value to the state.

I am new to React.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Firebase from '../Firebase';
import _ from 'lodash';
import '../App.css';


class Modify extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //state
    this.state = {
      personDetails: {},
      detail: ''
    };

    //bind
    this.renderData = this.renderData.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.saveEdit = this.saveEdit.bind(this);
  }

  //lifecycle
  componentDidMount() {
    Firebase.database().ref('/nannydetails').on('value', (snapshot) => {
      this.setState({
        personDetails: snapshot.val()
      })
    })
  }

  //handle change
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value.toLowerCase()
    });
  }

  //render data
  renderData() {
    return _.map(this.state.personDetails, (personDetail, key) => {
      return(
        <div className="pt-2 pb-1 m-2 border border-dark bg-warning row" key={key}>
          <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-3 text-right">
            <img src={require('./profile.png')} alt="cam"/>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-9 col-xs-9 p-2">
            <div className="headline">
              <h1>Full Name: </h1>
              <input className="form-control" type="text" name="fullName" defaultValue={personDetail.fullname} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
            <div className="headline">
              <h1>Contact Number: </h1>
              <input className="form-control" type="text" name="phone" defaultValue={personDetail.phone} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
            <div className="headline">
              <h1>Experience: </h1>
              <input className="form-control" type="text" name="experience" defaultValue={personDetail.experience} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
            <div className="headline">
              <h1>City: </h1>
              <input className="form-control" type="text" name="city" defaultValue={personDetail.city} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
            <div className="headline">
              <h1>State: </h1>
              <input className="form-control" type="text" name="state" defaultValue={personDetail.state} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-success" type="button" onClick={() => this.saveEdit(key)}><i className="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Save Edit</button>
            <button className="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick={() => this.handleDelete(key)}><i className="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    });
  }

  //handle save edit
  saveEdit(key) {
    // Firebase.database().ref(`/nannydetails/${key}`).push({
    //   fullname: this.state.fullname,
    //   phone: this.state.phone,
    //   experience: this.state.experience,
    //   city: this.state.city,
    //   state: this.state.state
    // });
    console.log(this.state.fullname);
    console.log(this.state.phone);
    console.log(this.state.experience);
    console.log(this.state.city);
    console.log(this.state.state);
  }

  //handle delete
  handleDelete(key) {
    const user= Firebase.database().ref(`/nannydetails/${key}`);
    user.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container mt-4">
        {this.renderData()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Modify;
```

Comment: `if the input tag value is not changed, then to pass the default value to the state` If the input doesn't change then react won't call the `onChange` callback to pass a value, default or not. They are probably undefined since all the properties you're trying to access will be on `this.state.personDetails`, i.e. `this.state.personDetails.fullname`. You should update your onChange handler to update these values instead of adding new properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the change handler to update/mutate the existing state instead of adding a new property(key), i.e. on `this.state.personDetails.X` vs. `this.state.X`

```
//handle change
handleChange(event) {
  // update the personDetails object you set in state on mount
  const newPersonDetails = { ...this.state.personDetails };
  newPersonDetails[event.target.name] = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
  this.setState({
    personDetails: newPersonDetails,
  });
}
```

[image: Edit wizardly-mcnulty-w1l09]

Answer (score 0):

Make this as a controlled component. Provide a initial state in you component and all the updated will done into the state & that will directly reflect into your component.

**Initial State:**

```
this.state = {
      personDetails: {
        fullname :'test'
      },
      detail: ''
    };
```

**Input Field**

```
input className="form-control" type="text" name="fullName" value={this.state.personDetail.fullname} onChange={this.handleChange}
```

Comment: actually i am using firebase. so i want to update the firebase data using reactjs

Comment: setState takes a callback function also.so, after updating the state in setState you can add you firebase function into the call back.
i.e:- setState({firstname:'hello'}, ()=>{firebase function})

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach is to have a main component take data from any api (firebase in your case) and second  child component which will be responsible to take input as props and return input(default/modified) on form action(submit). That way if data changes you get modified data else the default one.

```
 class FormComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        name: this.props.form.name,
    };

    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }


  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value});
  }

  handleChan
  render() {
        return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            value={this.state.name} 
            onChange={this.handleChange} 
          />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Refer to that fiddle for example. https://jsfiddle.net/papish19/ys6utv3k/7/

Comment: Please do not define and bind functions inside the render function, it is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

onChange is only triggered when the value of input changes. The defaultValue can be defined in the initial state, and the defaultValue is overwritten when the value of input changes.